# How do I get the local variables defined in a Python function?

Tags: python, static-analysis

I'm working on a project to do some static analysis of Python code. We're hoping to encode certain conventions that go beyond questions of style or detecting code duplication. I'm not sure this question is specific enough, but I'm going to post it anyway.

A few of the ideas that I have involve being able to build a certain understanding of how the various parts of source code work so we can impose these checks. For example, in part of our application that's exposing a REST API, I'd like to validate something like the fact that if a route is defined as a GET, then arguments to the API are passed as URL arguments rather than in the request body.

I'm able to get something like that to work by pulling all the routes, which are pretty nicely structured, and there are guarantees of consistency given the route has to be created as a route object. But once I know that, say, a given route is a GET, figuring out how the handler function uses arguments requires some degree of interpretation of the function source code.

Naïvely, something like `inspect.getsourcelines` will allow me to get the source code, but on further examination that's not the best solution because I immediately have to build interpreter-like features, such as figuring out whether a line is a comment, and then do something like use regular expressions to hunt down places where state is moved from the request context to a local variable.

Looking at tools like PyLint, they seem mostly focused on high-level "universals" of static analysis, and (at least on superficial inspection) don't have obvious ways of extracting this sort of understanding at a lower level.

Is there a more systematic way to get this representation of the source code, either with something in the standard library or with another tool? Or is the only way to do this writing a mini-interpreter that serves my purposes?

Comment: The built-in `ast` module is the fundamental tool for analyzing Python code.

Comment: Yes, a parser is probably a requirement for this.  But parsers are not the complete answer by a longshot; OP's request likely requires data flow analysis. The basic answer to OP's question "is there a more systematic way..." is "get a tool framework which includes the machinery you are going to need, because you can't afford to invent all that machinery yourself in most cases."    See my essay on LifeAfterParsing http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html